# Can I use the maven javadoc plugin (version 2.7) excludePackageNames attribute to exclude a package but not its subpackages?

Tags: maven, javadoc

I have a set of classes that I am generating javadoc for, some of which I want to exclude from the published javadoc. The structure is as follows:

```
com.company.package.classA
com.company.package.classB
com.company.package.subpackage.classC
com.company.package.subpackage.classD
```

I want to exclude all classes in "package" and include all classes in "subpackage". Setting:

```
<excludePackageNames>com.company.package</excludePackageNames>
```

excludes all subpackages beneath package.

Aside from restructuring the code, is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use 
[maven-javadoc-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/javadoc-mojo.html) to do it for you.

This is supported from version 2.7 and above.

Example:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>javadoc-jar</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>jar</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <!-- switch on dependency-driven aggregation -->
          <includeDependencySources>true</includeDependencySources>

          <dependencySourceExcludes>
            <!-- exclude ONLY commons-cli artifacts -->
            <dependencySourceExclude>commons-cli:*</dependencySourceExclude>
          </dependencySourceExcludes>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

```
     <configuration>
          <!-- switch on dependency-driven aggregation -->
          <includeDependencySources>true</includeDependencySources>

          <dependencySourceIncludes>
            <!-- include ONLY dependencies I control -->
            <dependencySourceInclude>org.test.dep:*</dependencySourceInclude>
          </dependencySourceIncludes>
     </configuration>
```

Comment: That looks interesting, and I might be able to use it elsewhere, but I don't think it does what I want here, which is to exclude "package" but include "subpackage" in my javadoc.